Did Chang'e (嫦娥) and Ne Zha (哪吒) ever interact?
In all Chinese mythology I would like to know if Chang'e and Nezha ever interacted at all.
If they ever did, were their feelings mutual? Did they know each other at all? I know both of their myths, and they're both my favorites.
I would love to know more about them and if they ever interacted.
